# JSON Schema- Spring Boot

Tags: json, spring-boot, jsonschema, vert.x, json-schema-validator

In my project I have dynamic objects (with different properties that I don't know prior) and I want to create for each of them a JSON SCHEMA with validators. I searched but I couldn't find a library to do that. I tried to use "Vert x" but I have to know the properties names in order to create the schema, and I can set as many validators as I want. Does anybody know what library I can use?

Answer (score 1):

I find your question a bit confusing - it sounds like you want to create a json schema without knowing the attributes in it, but a json schema is the definition of the attributes, so without knowing the attributes you can't have a schema.

Do you need to find some other way to drive your validation?